# F# - Write Deedle FrameData To CSV

Tags: f#, export-to-csv, deedle

I need to write a *Deedle* *FrameData* (including "ID" column and additional "Delta" column with blank entries) to CSV. While I can generate a 2D array of the *FrameData*, I am unable to write it correctly to a CSV file.

```
module SOQN = 

    open System
    open Deedle
    open FSharp.Data

    //  TestInput.csv
    //  ID,Alpha,Beta,Gamma
    //  1,no,1,hi
    //  ...

    //  TestOutput.csv
    //  ID,Alpha,Beta,Gamma,Delta
    //  1,"no","1","hi",""
    //  ...

    let inputCsv = @"D:\TestInput.csv"
    let outputCsv = @"D:\TestOutput.csv"
    let (df:Frame<obj,string>) = Frame.ReadCsv(inputCsv, hasHeaders=true, inferTypes=false, separators=",", indexCol="ID")

    // See http://www.fssnip.net/sj/title/Insert-Deedle-frame-into-Excel
    let data4Frame (frame:Frame<_,_>) = frame.GetFrameData()

    // See http://www.fssnip.net/sj/title/Insert-Deedle-frame-into-Excel
    let boxOptional obj =
        match obj with
        | Deedle.OptionalValue.Present obj -> box (obj.ToString()) 
        | _ -> box ""

    // See http://www.fssnip.net/sj/title/Insert-Deedle-frame-into-Excel
    let frameToArray (data:FrameData) =
        let transpose (array:'T[,]) =
          Array2D.init (array.GetLength(1)) (array.GetLength(0)) (fun i j -> array.[j, i])
        data.Columns
        |> Seq.map (fun (typ, vctr) -> vctr.ObjectSequence |> Seq.map boxOptional |> Array.ofSeq)
        |> array2D
        |> transpose

    let main = 
        printfn ""
        printfn "Output Deedle FrameData To CSV"
        printfn ""
        let dff = data4Frame df
        let rzlt = frameToArray dff     
        printfn "rzlt: %A" rzlt     
        do 
            use writer = new StreamWriter(outputCsv)
            writer.WriteLine("ID,Alpha,Beta,Gamma,Delta")
            // writer.WriteLine rzlt
        0

    [<EntryPoint>]
    main
    |> ignore
```

What am I missing?

Comment: May I ask why do you need write such function if there is standard one (`SaveCsv`)?

Comment: @FoggyFinder. I believe SaveCsv applies to _DataFrame_ but not to _FrameData_. Can you clarify?

Comment: oh, yes, sorry for that. I have never used `FrameData` before.

Comment: @FoggyFinder. No problem. I am trying to do some "data munging" of incoming CSV files.

Comment: why do not just use `Frame`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, I need to manipulate the rows separately from the header so that is why I am trying the _FrameData_ route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171640/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-matekus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use `FrameData` to do this - frame data is mostly internal and while there are some legitimate uses for it, I don't think it makes sense for this task.

If you simply want to add an empty `Delta` column to your input CSV, then you can do this:

```
let df : Frame<int, _> = Frame.ReadCsv("C:/temp/test-input.csv", indexCol="ID")
df.AddColumn("Delta", [])
df.SaveCsv("C:/temp/test-output.csv", ["ID"])
```

This does almost everything you need - it writes the `ID` column and the extra `Delta` column.

The only caveat is that it does not add the extra quotes around the data. This is not required by the CSV specification unless you need to escape a comma in a column and I don't think there is an easy way to get Deedle to do this.

So, I think then you'd have to write your own writing to a CSV file. The following shows how to do this, but it does not correctly escape quotes and commas (which is why you should use `SaveCsv` even if it does not put in the quotes when they're not needed):

```
use writer = new StreamWriter("C:/temp/test-output.csv")
writer.WriteLine("ID,Alpha,Beta,Gamma,Delta")
for key, row in Series.observations df.Rows do
  writer.Write(key)
  for value in Series.valuesAll row do
    writer.Write(",")
    writer.Write(sprintf "\"%O\"" (if value.IsSome then value.Value else box ""))
  writer.WriteLine()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the benefit of your expertise. I am _munging_ incoming csv files to output to a standard format. Usually, this means effectively working with the header and rows separately and bringing them together in the output CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the example of writing to csv from [source](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/FrameUtils.fs#L259-L351) of the library (it uses `FrameData` there)

After adding wrapper:

```
type FrameData with 
    member frameData.SaveCsv(path:string, ?includeRowKeys, ?keyNames, ?separator, ?culture) = 
      use writer = new StreamWriter(path)
      writeCsv writer (Some path) separator culture includeRowKeys keyNames frameData
```

you could write like this:

```
dff.SaveCsv outputCsv
```